# it's for printing high score for snake games created in java used txt file used for storage

Tags: java

txt file used for storage in the code I use I am getting from the file. it is storing the data in a text file but not reading from it and  prints high score as zero all the time and also send the error "ERROR reading scores"
data is not being stored in highScore and printing it as zero when I use it

link to the code file https://pastebin.com/YwF4Rxi2

```js
private  int score = 0;
    private int highScore = 0; 
 public void gameOver(Graphics g){
                 try {
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\wolf\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Snake Game\\build\\classes\\scoredata.txt", true));
                writer.println(score);     
                writer.close();
                } catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println("ERROR storing scores from file");
            }

          File file = new File("scoredata.txt");

           try  {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null)          
                { 
                    try {
                         int score2 = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());   
                          
                        if (score2 <= highScore)                     
                        {  
                            highScore = score2; 
                        }

                        line = reader.readLine();
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {

                    }
                    
                }
                reader.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("ERROR reading scores from file");
          
        String msg1 = "Game Over ";
        String msg2 = "SCORE IS " +score ;
        String msg4 = "HIGHSCORE  " +highScore ;  
        Font font = new Font("SAN_SERIF", Font.BOLD, 14);
        FontMetrics metrices = getFontMetrics(font);
        
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(msg1, (300 - metrices.stringWidth(msg1)) / 2 , 300/2);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString(msg2, (300 - metrices.stringWidth(msg2)) / 2 , 250/2);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString(msg4, (300 - metrices.stringWidth(msg4)) / 2 , 200/2);
    }
```

Comment: Instead of consuming the error `System.err.println("ERROR reading scores from file");` you need to instead wlite the full error to the console `ex.printStackTrace();` so that you can see what is actually happening. Run the code again with that change and look up the actual errer, or edit your question to include it. Also, edit this line to use the full file path `File file = new File("scoredata.txt");`

Comment: run:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: scoredata.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
this was the error I got after trying ex.printStackTrace();  i added Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\wolf\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Snake Game\\build\\classes\\scoredata.txt")); and got high score as zero again

Comment: Now do the same with `catch (NumberFormatException e1){ }` print the stack trace `e1.printStackTrace();`, and add some debugging inside the while loop to see if the file contents are being read `System.out.println("Line found: "+ line);`

Answer (score 1):

Your condition below is the problem

```
if (score2 <= highScore)                     
{  
   highScore = score2; 
}
```

Change the if condition as

```
score2 >= highScore
```

You should change the high score only if score2 is greater